# Hide one element in one slider only using data-slidein=1 in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having trouble to hide a background gray overlay element on my slider, I only have 4 sliders each slider has a `data-slidein` value from `1 to 4`. How can I hide the background gray overlay when the present slider are `slide-dataslide="1"`? the rest slider 2, 3, and 4 have a background overlay.

Simply I just want to `display: block` the background overlay in 2,3,4 and in `data-slidein="1"` is `display: none`.

In this case all slider have a each own background `slider-image` in each slider there's a `background gray overlay` using this `div ls-layers`, so how can I removed the `background gra overlay` on in `slider-image-1`? I don't know how to write this in jquery but I have an idea like this.

```
    if([data-slidein=1]){ 
      ls-layers background should hide 
    } else { 
    not }
```

I just need to find first slide then hide the `ls-layers` which is the background overlay.

```
<div class="ls-slide-backgrounds">
    <!-- Display none the gray-bg-gradient.png -->
    <div class="ls-wrapper ls-bg-outer">
        <div class="ls-wrapper ls-bg-wrap">
            <img src="slider-image-1.png" class="ls-bg" data-slidein="1" data-slideout="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Display the gray-bg-gradient.png -->
    <div class="ls-wrapper ls-bg-outer">
        <div class="ls-wrapper ls-bg-wrap">
            <img src="slider-image-1.png" class="ls-bg" data-slidein="2" data-slideout="2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ls-layers"></div>
```

Comment: Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: I can't figure out when the single div `ls-layers` is going to be hidded, this div is covering all the elements and you want the elent don't cover just the data-slide-in=1?

Comment: if data-slidein=1 === data-slide=1 like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using a `div` tag to do that, so...

You can do this just with css

```
div[data-slidein=1]{
   display: block;
}
```

but if you nedd javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[data-slidein=1]').hide();
});
```

if you want this to hide after something, place the code inside a function and call it, or a listener

```
$(document).delegate('.my-button', 'click', function(){
    $('div[data-slidein=1]').hide();
});
```

Comment: How can I conditioned the data-slidein=1? Like If data-slidein=1(hide a some of element in data 1) else (display an element)? Cause this is not a static content its from a wordpress plugin where I need to condition the function.

Comment: I saw the code your commented before, you mean, hide the some parent of data-slidein=1?

Comment: If is this, you can use some code like this `$('div[data-slidein=1]').closest('.class-name').hide();`

Comment: I will comment above the html code, just give me a second.

Comment: already updated the question with the html code, I hope you can help me figuring it out the solution.